# Yii2: Failed creating own template with GII module (advance template)

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I have some problem here
I have created an advance template with yii2, and i've followed "The Gii code generation tool" from http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-gii.html

1. copy folder default template

   > cp [YII_ROOT]\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\generators\crud\default
   >   [YII_ROOT]\backend\generator\crud
2. edit `[YII_ROOT]\backend\generator\crud\default\views\_form.php`

   > ```
   >     <?= "<?php " ?>$form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
   >     <?= "<?=" ?> $form->errorSummary($model) ?> <!-- ADDED HERE -->
   > <?php foreach ($generator->getColumnNames() as $attribute) {
   >     if (in_array($attribute, $safeAttributes)) {
   >         echo "    <?= " . $generator->generateActiveField($attribute) . " ?>\n\n";
   >     }
   > } ?>
   > ```
3. edit [YII_ROOT]\backend\main.php

   > ```
   > return [
   >     'bootstrap' => ['gii'],
   >     'modules' => [ 'gii' => [
   >             'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
   >             'generators' => [ //here
   >                 'crud' => [ //name generator
   >                     'class' => 'yii\gii\generators\crud\Generator', //class generator
   >                     'templates' => [ //setting for out templates
   >                         'myTemplate' => '@app\generator\crud\default', //name template => path to template
   >                     ]
   >                 ]
   >             ],
   >         ],
   >     ], ];
   > ```
4. generate with gii (in this case generate CRUD)

The problem is, i still can't find the difference of _form.php template. what should i do?